# How to open multiple URLs and capture multiple links as images using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to implement some codes to capture each image in links.
But if I run this code, then I only get last link's images.
how to I get all images correctly?
I found it relates to closure, but it is going likewise.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({});

var dst = casper.cli.options["dst"];
var toon_id = casper.cli.options["id"];
var lastno = casper.cli.options["no"];
var no;
for (no=1; no<lastno;no++){
    var nox = no;
    var uri = 'http://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=' + toon_id + '&no=' + nox;
    (function(m){
        casper.start(uri, function() {
            var i;
            for(i=0;;i++){
                var id = '#content_image_' + i;

                if( casper.exists(id) == false ) break;
                this.captureSelector(m + '_' + i + '.png', id);
            }
        });

        casper.run();    
        console.log('No '+ m + '. has rendered' );
    })(nox);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `casper.start()` and `casper.run()` only once in your script, `start()` overwrites all internal data of the `casper` instance when you use the same instance for each iteration. Additionally, CasperJS is asynchronous, so you have to use step functions such as all `then*()` and `wait*()` functions to be sure that the previous step finished.

You can use `thenOpen()` instead of `start()`;

```
casper.start();
for (no=1; no<lastno;no++){
    var nox = no;
    var uri = 'http://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=' + toon_id + '&no=' + nox;
    (function(m){
        casper.thenOpen(uri, function() {
            var i;
            for(i=0;;i++){
                var id = '#content_image_' + i;

                if( casper.exists(id) == false ) break;
                this.captureSelector(m + '_' + i + '.png', id);
            }
        });

        console.log('No '+ m + '. has rendered' );
    })(nox);
}

casper.run();
```

---

Note that PhantomJS' rendering is very inefficient. It would probably be better to [`download()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) the image directly instead of making a cropped screenshot of it.